# Django : Displaying ManyToManyField in admin page as a Table

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following two models.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question_body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    question_response = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_body 

class SIGRound(models.Model):
    sig = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=SIG_CHOICES)
    round_number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    round_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

I want to use the SIGRound from the admin page and since it is a many to many field, many answers on StackOverflow suggested to use `filter_horizontal` or `inline`

So I implemented both and checked out how they looked, `filter_horizontal` does not give me what I want and with `inline` it looks like this:

[image]
This is the code I am currently using:

```
class QuestionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SIGRound.questions.through

@admin.register(SIGRound)
class SIGRoundAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[QuestionInline]
```

But I want to display this field as a table, similar to `list_display` in the normal admin page, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You *do* wnat an inline; it should just be a TabularInline.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I am currently using TabularInline, but the display is as shown in the image. Is there something I am missing?